# Lucene 3.5.0 QueryParser doesn't find any results while programmatically generated query does

Tags: java, lucene

This has been baffling me recently, and I can't seem to find a suitable explanation anywhere.

If I run a query built using the Query API, it works perfectly well.

```
TermQuery sourceQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("source", "CNN"));
```

Running `results = searcher.search(sourceQuery, 30)` and checking `results.totalHits` shows me a value of 159.

However, in the same program, I set up a `QueryParser` (my default field is called `text`):

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_35);
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_35,
      "text", analyzer);
```

and input the command-line query

```
source:CNN
```

I get **no** results. Running this command on [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) *does* give me a result. Does anyone have an idea what's happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have used the wrong Analyzer for the QueryParser object. Note that:

1. When you build your own Term object, the term's text is in upper case.
2. You give StandardAnalyzer to QueryParser, so the term's text is converted to lower case (by StandardAnalyzer).
3. Luke's default analyzer is KeywordAnalyzer, which preserves the case (i.e. upper case) you specify the term in.

I guess your terms are in upper case (or turned into upper case) when you index the text. That explains why approach 1 and 3 work, but 2 does not because the cases do not match. In general, it's a good idea to [use the same Analyzer when indexing and when searching](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Why_is_it_important_to_use_the_same_analyzer_type_during_indexing_and_search.3F), or at least pay attention to the case.

Comment: Wow, did not know that. So if I'm storing the field for source with the Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS, what Analyzer should I use while querying? Also, I wouldn't want the KeywordAnalyzer for searching the "text" field, would I? (the huge paragraph of text). So must I analyze ALL of my terms the same way?

Comment: If your field is not analyzed, you want to use something simple like KeywordAnalyzer or WhitespaceAnalyzer. Just be careful about whether the analyzer changes case, omits stop words, or removes "'s". You want the terms that come out of the analyzer to match that NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS field. You don't have to analyze all fields the same way. Take a look at PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper.

Comment: I think one clarification might help you. The query-time Analyzer is given the text you entered as the query string and Lucene forms TermQueries from the tokens the Analyzer spews out. So the query-time Analyzer never sees anything in the index, it only sees your query strings. For expample, if you analyzed a field using StandardAnalyzer, it's perfectly fine to use the KeywordAnalyzer at query time, just that you must be careful about what string you give it -- you must give it the exact token that the StandardAnalyzer produced at indexing time.

Comment: That's a useful tip; though I don't think I can afford being restrictive in the type of queries I allow at query time.